# C# BIG Endian Format for long value

Tags: c#, byte, endianness, bitconverter

I am trying to do the following regarding my specification:

The sales counter with the number of bytes N is starting with byte 0 in the BIG
ENDIAN format stored as a two's complement representation ("signed"). N corresponds
the number of bytes required to encode the sales counter. To have to
At least 5 bytes / 40 bits are used for the revenue counter.

and for this i have created the following code in C#

```
private static byte[] EncodeUmsatz(long umsatz)
{
    // This gives an 8-byte array
    byte[] umsatzBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(umsatz);
    // Pad with zeroes to get 16 bytes
    int length = 16 * ((umsatzBytes.Length + 15) / 16);
    Array.Resize(ref umsatzBytes, length);
    // reverse to get big-endian array
    Array.Reverse(umsatzBytes, 0, umsatzBytes.Length);
    return umsatzBytes;
}
```

The Property `IsLittleEndian` of the `BitConverter` is false. So this should be right, or?

But the Test with an external tool says

> "The calculated sales counter does not match the encrypted sales counter (see the DECRYPTED_TURNOVER_VALUE parameter), please check the sales counter encoding (BIG endian, two's complement) or the AES key used."

What I do not know if my code makes a two's complement representation?

I am not the specialist with bytes so has someone an idea what I can try

Answer (score 0):

so the problem is solved - the c# code is correct for big endian - the problem was the value for the input parameter was wrong